# Magento 2 - How to get attribute options value of eav entity?

Tags: magento2, database, eav

How can I get the attribute options values of eav entity?
I found solution only for magento 1.x but M2 I don't know.
M1:

```
$attr = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter('specialty')->getData()[0];
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attr['attribute_id']);
$src =  $attributeModel->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Anyone know, show me step by step, pls!Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get it
Can you give an example of a working code where you
get magento attribute parameters programmatically
Like here
https://pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/get-magento-attribute-options-programmatically/
it didn't work for me.

Comment: -- Divya
I didn't succeed with your code. Here is a working example for finding product data <?php use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php'; $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State'); $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); $sku ='YL-YM-101'; // my product sku $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $productObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); $product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku); echo $p

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you can add to the constructor of your class an instance of `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` like this:

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}
```

then you can use that in your class

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: How to get "value" and "label"?

Comment: see how the result looks like. Var dump it or something.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> int(1) ["label"]=> object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#1504 (2) { ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> string(7) "Enabled" ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> array(0) { } } } [1]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> int(2) ["label"]=> object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#1494 (2) { ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> string(8) "Disabled" ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> array(0) { } } } }

Comment: Okey! I resolved => $attributesArrays = array();
     
     foreach($options as $cal=>$val){
      $attributesArrays[$val['value']] = $val['label']->getText();
     }

Comment: Small but important remark: If available, better to use Module Service Layer. For eav attributes it's `\Magento\Eav\Api\Attribute RepositoryInterface`. Anything not marked as @api treated as private and can be removed in minor releases.

Comment: @KAndy Good remark. You can write that as an answer. I think it's far better than mine.

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com  get value and label like below
<?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $fieldValue) echo ' selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $option['label']->getText();?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: Could you post this as a step-step answer?? I don't know how to create a module like that in magento2, so I don;t know how to use that code.

Comment: @zekia maybe this helps: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: @Marius I've read this article but there's a big step between a basic module and a module with controllers and blocks. I can't fill the blanks there. That's why I asked for a more detailed step-step answer.

Answer (score 10):

Use the following code to get all attribute options.

```
function getExistingOptions( $object_Manager ) {

$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$optionsExists = array();

foreach($options as $option) {
    $optionsExists[] = $option['label'];
}

return $optionsExists;

 }
```

Please Can you click here for more detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/get-magento-attribute-options-programmatically/

Answer (score 6):

I use the Api Service Layer `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface` suggested by @kandy in comments on @marius answer.

Inject the service data member in your constructor as follow.

```
protected $eavAttributeRepository;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepositoryInterface,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepositoryInterface;
    ...
}
```

And the you can get the attribute using this.

```
$attribute = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'attribute_code_here'
);
// var_dump($attribute->getData());
```

In order to get attribute option values array, use this.

```
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it simply call below code inside your Block file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Package\Block;

class Blockname extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productAttributeRepository;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
        array $data = [] 
    ){        
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
    } 

    public function getAllBrand(){
        $manufacturerOptions = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('manufacturer')->getOptions();       
        $values = array();
        foreach ($manufacturerOptions as $manufacturerOption) { 
           //$manufacturerOption->getValue();  // Value
            $values[] = $manufacturerOption->getLabel();  // Label
        }
        return $values;
    }  
}
```

Call inside your phtml file,

```
<div class="manufacturer-name">
      <?php $getOptionValue = $this->getAllBrand();?>
      <?php foreach($getOptionValue as $value){ ?>
           <span><?php echo $value;?></span>
      <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't return the options for attributes configured to use `swatch` inputs, like `color`. The `getOptions()` method is hard coded to certain input types, like "dropdowns", so it skips the swatch input options. Just a heads up if anyone else runs in to that.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, How I achieve this same but for Admin. I need these option value for Grid column filter. Can you please tell me.

Comment: How to get item attribute values based on store-level on order summary section at checkout Magento 2

Comment: @Rakesh, does it work in magento 2.4

Answer (score 4):

Inject an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository` in your constructor (in a block, helper class or wherever):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $_productAttributeRepository
 */
protected $_productAttributeRepository;

/**
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
 * ...
 */
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
    ...
}
```

Then create a method in your class to get the attribute by code:

```
/**
 * Get single product attribute data 
 *
 * @return Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface
 */
public function getProductAttributeByCode($code)
{
    $attribute = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get($code);
    return $attribute;
}
```

You can then call this method like so, e.g. inside a .phtml file

```
$attrTest = $block->getProductAttributeByCode('test');
```

Then you can make calls on the attribute object, e.g.

1. Get options: `$attribute->getOptions()`
2. Get frontend label for each store: `$attrTest->getFrontendLabels()`
3. Debug the data array: `echo '> ' . print_r($attrTest->debug(), true);`

> debug: Array (
>       [attribute_id] => 274
>       [entity_type_id] => 4
>       [attribute_code] => product_manual_download_label
>       [backend_type] => varchar
>       [frontend_input] => text
>       [frontend_label] => Product Manual Download Label
>       [is_required] => 0
>       [is_user_defined] => 1
>       [default_value] => Product Manual Download
>       [is_unique] => 0
>       [is_global] => 0
>       [is_visible] => 1
>       [is_searchable] => 0
>       [is_filterable] => 0
>       [is_comparable] => 0
>       [is_visible_on_front] => 0
>       [is_html_allowed_on_front] => 1
>       [is_used_for_price_rules] => 0
>       [is_filterable_in_search] => 0
>       [used_in_product_listing] => 0
>       [used_for_sort_by] => 0
>       [is_visible_in_advanced_search] => 0
>       [position] => 0
>       [is_wysiwyg_enabled] => 0
>       [is_used_for_promo_rules] => 0
>       [is_required_in_admin_store] => 0
>       [is_used_in_grid] => 1
>       [is_visible_in_grid] => 1
>       [is_filterable_in_grid] => 1
>       [search_weight] => 1 )

Comment: This is a very well explained answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
      /* to load the Product */
  $_product = $block->getProduct();
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $attributeSet = $objectManager- 
   >create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
  $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($_product->getAttributeSetId());
  $_attributeValue  = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
```