# Programatically delete custom attribute options

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-options

I'm trying to delete all custom attribute options not contained within a specific options array as follows:

```
 /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
        $attribute = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode);

        $sourceModel = $this->tableFactory->create();
        $sourceModel->setAttribute($attribute);

        $options = $sourceModel->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if(!in_array($option, $usedOptions)) {
                $option->delete();
            }
        }
```

How would i achieve this? $option->delete() throws an error - Call to a member function delete() on array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take a look:

**vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php**

```
public function addAttributeOption($option)
{
        $optionTable = $this->setup->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
        $optionValueTable = $this->setup->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value');

        if (isset($option['value'])) {
            foreach ($option['value'] as $optionId => $values) {
                $intOptionId = (int)$optionId;
                if (!empty($option['delete'][$optionId])) {
                    if ($intOptionId) {
                        $condition = ['option_id =?' => $intOptionId];
                        $this->setup->getConnection()->delete($optionTable, $condition);
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                 ......

                $condition = ['option_id =?' => $intOptionId];
                $this->setup->getConnection()->delete($optionValueTable, $condition);
                foreach ($values as $storeId => $value) {
                    $data = ['option_id' => $intOptionId, 'store_id' => $storeId, 'value' => $value];
                    $this->setup->getConnection()->insert($optionValueTable, $data);
                }
            }
        }
        ......
}
```

We can see how to use `addAttributeOption()` method to delete custom options. Our code should be:

```
    ......
    $options = $sourceModel->getAllOptions();

    foreach ($options as $optionId => $value) {

        //We can use if condition
        $options['value'][$optionId] = true;  
        $options['delete'][$optionId] = true;

    }

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $setup;
    $setup->addAttributeOption($options)
```

How to get attribute options value: [Magento 2 - How to get attribute options value of eav entity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105167/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-options-value-of-eav-entity)

**UPDATE:**
Testing with playground: [How can I bootstrap Magento 2 in a test.php script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2)

```
<?php
class TestApp
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {
    public function launch()
    {
        //Our code goes here:
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $eavAttribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $attribute */
        $attribute = $eavAttribute->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

       //foreach ($options as $optionId => $value) {
            //We can use if condition
            //For example
            $options['value'][4] = true;
            $options['delete'][4] = true;
      //}

        $setupObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $setupObject **/

        $setupObject->addAttributeOption($options);
        //the method must end with this line
        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Magento 1 version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250562/magento-delete-attribute-values-options-mysql).

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this response, this doesn't seem to be deleting the options though. Can you explain why i need to call addAttributeOption($options), and does this imply the option manipulation this should be done from within the UpgradeData class? Currently i'm using an external source file to add an attribute and it's options, it's within this file that i would like to delete all options that have been created but are no longer in use.

Comment: I update my code, I tested with playground file.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh,
I have to remove these options, from json
"OptionValues": [ 
    { 
     "OptionId": "01",  
     "OptionName": "Test3" 
    },
    { 
     "OptionId": "Null",
     "OptionName" : "Test"
    }

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, how to delete multiple options at a time ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar in this code make an array $options in $setupObject->addAttributeOption($options); and dont forget to use di instead object manager, using object manager is bad practice!
$options - array of optionIds and values
foreach ($options as $optionId => $value) {
            $options['value'][$optionId] = true;
            $options['delete'][$optionId] = true;
}
$setupObject->addAttributeOption($options);

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following code :
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/delete-attribute-options-magento-2/

```
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$id = $attribute->getAttributeId();
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

foreach ($options as $option) {
echo 'Delete label : '.$option['label'].PHP_EOL;  
$options['delete'][$option['value']] = true; 
$options['value'][$option['value']] = true;
}

$eavSetup = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
 $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($options);
```

Comment: Above url is display 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

I tried **$eavSetup->addAttributeOption** ,But it's not working for text swatch type attributes. So got a way which is working for all type of attributes.

> Reference Class: Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Entity\AttributeTest

> Method : removeAttributeOption

```
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
// $optionId = option id which you want to delete 
$removalMarker = [
    'option' => [
        'value' => [$optionId => []],
        'delete' => [$optionId => '1'],
    ],
];
$attribute->addData($removalMarker);
$attribute->save($attribute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface, it has method delete which you can use.

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface
 */
protected $attributeOptionManagement;
...
$this->attributeOptionManagement->delete(
                'catalog_product',
                $attributeId,
                $attributeOptionId
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionManagement::delete($entityType, $attributeCode, $optionId)