# Magento 2 remove unused product attribute values

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Is it possible to remove any unused product attribute values? All the answer I find seem to be related to magento 1 and not 2.

I have a product attribute called size and it has around 100 different values connected to it. However I am not sure which ones are used and which ones are not. Therefore I would like to run a script or a sql statement to run to remove all of the ones which aren't connected to any products

Comment: Do you have a filter to determine if a value is unused or used? Or this is what you are asking.

Comment: I have updated my question, does that help?

Comment: How many products do you have? what do you mean, values connected to it? How did you identified these 100 different values?

Comment: Around 750 products

Answer (score 1):

I think you could to it with a small extension like:

- get all products with something like:

  ```
  $products = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('your_attr', array('neq' => ''));
  ```
- save in an array all the option values of your custom attribute from all the products

  ```
  $my_custom_attribute_values = []; 
  foreach($products as $p) {   
     array_push($my_custom_attribute_values, $p->yor_attr); 
  }
  ```
- get all possible attribute values, something like:

  ```
  $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
  $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
  foreach($options as $opt){
      array_push($option_values, $opt->value);
  }
  ```
- diff the two arrays:

  ```
  array_diff($option_values, $my_custom_attribute_values);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then how would I delete them as your code would only find the ones not used

Comment: well once you have the unused options you can delete them. You can do it programmatically as suggested https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/programatically-delete-custom-attribute-options here for example, you can use REST API... it's up to you to complete the code, this is just a flow you could follow.