# Magento 2 add custom block in custom layout

Tags: magento2

Our designer works in our own custom layout, located in:

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace
```

There we modify the default layout `Magento_LayeredNavigation::view.phtml`

Now we want to add a custom block to this file:

```
$block->something();
```

inside the structure of filter.phtml

We wrote a custom module (app/code/vendor/namespace) with a block and we add this information in:

```
app/code/vendor/namespace/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_layered.xml
app/code/vendor/namespace/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

**Now our question:**

Is it correct that we add this new block in the custom design structure of view.phtml? - Or do we have to move the whole file (view.phtml) into
the custom module ( which is bad for the designers .. cause the layout infos
are mixed in several modules then! )

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your **filter.phtml file** into your custom module. This way is good for you. Because you have already create new module for your custom file template.This is the proper way to use magento specific way because in future if you remove your extra changes from filter file at that time you have to just disable or remove that module and your functionality is close and default functionality is working.

If you want to change inside theme filter.phtml file this is mot create any problem for you but you have create already module then use inside module tempate file is best way.

Comment: Hi .. i dont know if i understand your answer. When i move the whole phtml into my custom module than the designers have to add the layout changes there .. i think this is not a good way. I hoped thar a can leave the phtml in the design folder and use xml to place the new block and adress it in the layout folder.

Comment: You have to ask your designer for that, files comes from this module, This is proper way but you can use customize inside your theme also

Comment: You have to think site performance level not for your designer and designer can also design inside module file. Most of extension are follow this way not doing inside theme.

Comment: Plz let me know if any issues.

Comment: Ok,

i now move the view.phtml to my custom module and add a static content .. works fine.
A also add a new Block to the structure (without a template) .. i only want to return a value!

Comment: In catalog_category_layered.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Catalog\MyBlock"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>

Comment: In view.phtml
<div class="block filter">
<?php echo $block->something();?>


But this do not work! (Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method)

Whats wrong?

Comment: My Block looks something like this:
class MyBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
public function something()

Comment: You have to declare view.phtml into your xml block

Comment: <block class="your\class\name" templates="Vendor_Namespace::view.phtml />

Comment: Thanks. The reason behind this all is, that i want all option item values from a given multiselct filter attribute ( used as filter ) and i do not find a solution to parse this direct in the view ( f.e. foreach ($filterItem->getOptions() ... ) i only find a solution by block: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105167/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-options-value-of-eav-entity

Is there a solution ( like Magento1 ) to get all options for a given product attribute ( multiselect) in a phtml? Or is it only possible by using a block or Helper?

Comment: i add a new post with detail informations: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133388/magento2-a-block-to-given-phtml ..

Comment: If you useful, feel free to close this quesrion using accept answer.