# Magento2 a block to given phtml

Tags: magento2

I want a new custom block to get all option values to a given filter product attribute in `Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml`.

We have our own design folder which overrides the default layout:

[image]

Now i want to modify this `view.phtml` with a new Block which we build in a custom module:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyNamespace\Block\Catalog;

class AttributeOptions extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        $aReturnValues = array('A', 'B');
        return $aReturnValues;
    }
}
```

In our module we add this:

**app\code\MyVendor\MyNamespace\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_layered.xml**

With:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="MyVendor\MyNamespace\Block\Catalog\AttributeOptions"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Than we edit the `view.phtml` and and this:

[image]

We activate the whole module but we get an

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid
>   method exception.

Can anyone tell us the correct way to modify a phtml with a new block which has no own template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method exception.

Already they declared **Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml** to this block **app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/Block/Navigation.php**.

You only override the phtml so it is still render the method from old block so it throws **method not found** error. If you want to customize the block you need to override the block also.

for override the block add the below content in your `app/code/vendor/module_name/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="MyVendor\MyNamespace\Block\Catalog\AttributeOptions" />
</config>
```

after that your custom theme view.phtml render method from your `MyVendor\MyNamespace\Block\Catalog\AttributeOptions.php`

no need this declaration `\app\code\MyVendor\MyNamespace\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_layered.xml`. this is not a way to override block

Comment: I only want to add a new block inside a given layout ( /app/design/... )  from a custom block. Do i realy have to rewrite the complete Navigation Block ?