# How to get last added attribute option id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am adding options to attribute programmatically as explained here http://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-add-options-attribute-magento2/.
What i want is to get the id of that attribute option to save it to my custom db table. How to achieve this?
thanks

Comment: what is your actuall question `last added attribute option id in magento 2?` or `attribute option to save it to your custom db table`

Comment: I just need last added option id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I am getting last added attribute option id. I am getting the id by passing last added option label.

```
$attributeInfo=$this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code',['eq'=>"attribute_id"])
               ->getFirstItem(); 
$option_id = $attributeInfo->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeValue);//$attributeValue is the label of last added attribute option;
```

Please comment if there is any better way.

Answer (score 1):

At magento2,
If you want a  options then follow Marius answer
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105171/4564

```
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

give  list of options  with value and label

```
$OptionInarray=array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $options->getValue();  // Value
    $option->getLabel();  // Label
   $OptionInarray[$options->getValue()] = $option->getLabel();
}
```

here, ***$options->getValue(); is give u list option id of this attribute***

Then using `krsort()` you can get last order id fro  `$OptionInarray`

`krsort($OptionInarray);`..Then `array_values(krsort($OptionInarray))[0];` , we can get last id