# Magento 2 :- How to get newly added options id of product attribute & Deleted option id of attribute

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-attribute, eav-attributes, attribute-options

I want to get lastly added product attribute options id and also need to deleted option id in the following event: **catalog_entity_attribute_save_after**

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Please see this link, may be helpful to you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153227/how-to-get-last-added-attribute-option-id-in-magento-2#153247

Comment: Thanks for your reply ma'am, but every time when attribute saves after an event called then this will give again the same value. or if I'll add multiple options than how to get other options id.