# How to display custom attribute brand value on custom phtml file?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I want to display custom attribute brand value on custom phtml file.

I tried Below code in phtml file but not working

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>
```

Is there any solution please share it.

Comment: have you check $_product object contain valid data or not?

Comment: Please set "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to yes for brand attribute and check again

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105167/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-options-value-of-eav-entity 
Check This Link i use this link and i get solution and this is working