# Magento2: Get attribute code & attribute details from attribute Id in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes

Helllo All,

I want to retrieve attribute code and attribute details from attribute id. In magento1, I am doing it as:

```
$attrCode = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attributeId)->getAttributeCode();
```

How can we get this in magento 2.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    $eavModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');
    $attr = $eavModel->load($attributeId);
    $attributeCode = $attr->getAttributeCode();//Get attribute code from its id
    echo $attributeCode;

     /*Get attribute details*/
    $attributeDetails = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attributeCode);
    print_r($attributeDetails->getData());
```

Comment: You don't specify the source class for `$this->eavConfig`

Comment: @domdambrogia you can follow here, its worked.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105171/70258

Comment: where you are using $attr?

Comment: How to fetch for multiple attribute code like `color` and `size` can I pass an array?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface and inject it into your class.

You can use the "get" method of the repository class. This works for me even if I supplied an attribute_id instead of the attribute_code. I've tested it in 2.2.6.

```
class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
    protected $repository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $repository
    ){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
    public function test($attributeId){
        $attribute = $this->repository->get($attributeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the best answer that doesn't use the object manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
 /*
  * Get attribute info by attribute code and entity type
  */ 
$attributeCode = 'color';
$entityType = 'catalog_product';

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$attributeInfo = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                               ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);

//var_dump($attributeInfo->getData()); exit;

/**
 * Get all options name and value of the attribute
 */ 
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                             
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();

//var_dump($attributeOptionAll->getData()); exit;
```